# How to pass data from one page to another with react router dom Link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-router

I'm trying to pass an ID from one page to another by using the state of Link.

I'm trying to get the value from purchases page and send it to the purchases details. This is the code that I'm using :

```
 <Link 
    to={{
      pathname: "/purchases-detail",
      state: { transactionId: item?.transactionId },
  }}/>
```

How to access and use transacationId in the next page?

Comment: If your other page is rendered via route then you can do `const { transactionId }  =  props.location.state`

Comment: How can I import location in the next page?

Comment: How are you rendering your next page ? Is it rendered via Route ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing it to state, you could simply add it to the path as a parameter

```
 <Link to={{
   pathname: `/purchases-detail${item?.transactionId}`,
   }}/>
```

Then in the details page you can use query-string from this.props.location.search

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a parameter in the path:

The state can be retrieved in the props of the detail page

```
this.props.location.state.transactionId
```

But your detail page must be rendered by the router